# Echo the next article or previous article with urls

Tags: php, html, xhtml

The **nest.php** page below contains a multidimensional array **$laws**, and it contains **groups** of laws with **chapters** that comprise of several **articles** in them.

I have made the **PREVIOUS Article** and **NEXT Article** dynamic url links to echo back one article after another sequentially.

But what PHP Code should I add to these (2) urls to skip to the next chapter when the last article of a particular chapter has been echoed?

```
<?php
session_start();

$laws=array(
       "group1"=>array(
                      "1"=>array(
                                "1"=>"This is article (1) in chapter (1) of (group1)",
                                "2"=>"This is article (2) in chapter (1) of (group1)",
                                "3"=>"This is article (3) in chapter (1) of (group1)",
                                ),
                      "2"=>array(
                                "1"=>"This is article (1) in chapter (2) of (group1)",
                                "2"=>"This is article (2) in chapter (2) of (group1)",
                                "3"=>"This is article (3) in chapter (2) of (group1)",
                                ),
                       ),
       "group2"=>array(
                      "1"=>array(
                                "1"=>"This is article (1) in chapter (1) of (group2)",
                                "2"=>"This is article (2) in chapter (1) of (group2)",
                                "3"=>"This is article (3) in chapter (1) of (group2)",
                                ),
                      "2"=>array(
                                "1"=>"This is article (1) in chapter (2) of (group2)",
                                "2"=>"This is article (2) in chapter (2) of (group2)",
                                "3"=>"This is article (3) in chapter (2) of (group2)",
                                ),

       )
       );


if(isset($_GET['group']) && isset($_GET['chapter']) && isset($_GET['article'])){
$grp = $_GET['group'];
$chap = $_GET['chapter'];
$art = $_GET['article'];    
}else{
$grp = 'group1';
$chap = '1';
$art = '1';  
}

if(isset($laws[$grp][$chap][$art])){
$_SESSION['group'] = $grp;
$_SESSION['chapter'] = $chap;
$_SESSION['article'] = $art;    
}

$group = $_SESSION['group'];
$chapter = $_SESSION['chapter'];
$article = $_SESSION['article'];

$previousarticle = $_SESSION['article'];


echo $laws[$group][$chapter][$article]; // ALL ARTICLES TO BE ECHOED HERE!!!!!

echo '<br/>';

?>
  <!-------------- PREVIOUS Article and NEXT Article URLS ------------------->
<a href="nest.php?group=<?php echo $group; ?>&chapter=<?php echo $chapter; ?>&article=<?php echo --$previousarticle ; ?>" style="text-decoration: none;">PREVIOUS ARTICLE</a>
<br/>
<a href="nest.php?group=<?php echo $group; ?>&chapter=<?php echo $chapter;  ?>&article=<?php echo ++$article ; ?>" style="text-decoration: none;">NEXT ARTICLE</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add one more condition before link as below

```
<!-------------- PREVIOUS Article and NEXT Article URLS ------------------->
  <?php 
  $prvartcle = $previousarticle -1 ;

  if(!empty($laws[$group][$chapter][$prvartcle])) {?>
<a href="test1.php?group=<?php echo $group; ?>&chapter=<?php echo $chapter; ?>&article=<?php echo --$previousarticle ; ?>" style="text-decoration: none;">PREVIOUS ARTICLE</a>
<?php } ?>
<br/>

<?php 
$nextart = $article+1;
if(!empty($laws[$group][$chapter][$nextart])) {?>
<a href="test1.php?group=<?php echo $group; ?>&chapter=<?php echo $chapter;  ?>&article=<?php echo ++$article ; ?>" style="text-decoration: none;">NEXT ARTICLE</a>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

All necessary comments are written where ever they necessary..

```
<?php

$no_of_groups = count($laws);
// counting number of groups in laws

/* check if there is any selected by any user or by link. If there is nothing selected, do select first group in laws automatically */
if (isset($_GET['group']) and !empty($_GET['group'])) {
    $fgroup = $_GET['group'];
} else {
    $fgroup = $laws[0]; // selects first group in laws
}

/* check if there is any article selected by user or by link. If there is nothing selected, do select first article in a group automatically */
if (isset($_GET['article']) and !empty($_GET['article'])) {
    $farticle = $_GET['article'];
} else {
    $farticle = $fgroup[0];     // selects first article in a group
}

$no_of_article_in_this_group = count($farticle);
// counting number of article in selected or default group


/* Now, we are checking if there is chapters selected by user or by link. If there is nothing selected, do select first chapter in an article */
if (isset($_GET['chap']) and !empty($_GET['chap'])) {
    $fchap = $_GET['chap'];
} else {
    $fchap = $farticle[0];      // selects first chapter in an article
}

$no_of_chapters_in_this_article = count($fchap);
// counting number of chapter in selected article or default article

$page_url = "nest.php";

/* We are checking, is there is next chapter available in an article, if yes then move to next chapter in an array else we will be current chapter */

if (!empty(next($fchap))) {
    $nxt_chapter = next($fchap);
} else {
    $nxt_chapter = current($fchap);
}

/* We are checking, is there is previous chapter available in an article, if yes then move to previous chapter in an array else we will be current chapter */

if (!empty(prev($fchap))) {
    $prv_chapter = prev($fchap);
} else {
    $prv_chapter = current($fchap);
}


// Below, making next and prev links ready to use

$page_next_url = $page_url . "?group=$fgroup&article=$farticle&chap=$nxt_chapter";
$page_prev_url = $page_url . "?group=$fgroup&article=$farticle&chap=$prv_chapter";


?>
```

let me know if you need more information

Comment: This may be the answer but you needed to shade more light. This multidimesonal array has ** groups => chapters => articles.**